# Updating project_name.dll.config not reflected in my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2019

I am very new to C# and just got into a new project where I have a Plugin packager that converts my C# project into `project_name.plugin` and generates `project_name.dll.config` which equal to app.config file.
the app.config contains Paths.
However, when I update the paths in project_name.dll.config file, the project_name.plugin doesn't reflect the new paths.

e.g. let's say I want to update  to <Path1_Updated> the Plugin will still read the old .

What I am looking for is a way to update the app.config dynamically from the generated project_name.dll.config.

app.config:

```
<configuration>            
    <applicationSettings>
        <project_name.AppProperties>
            <setting name="mydata1_file_location" serializeAs="String">
                <value><Path1></value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="mydata2_file_location" serializeAs="String">
                <value><Path2></value>
            </setting>
        </project_name.AppProperties>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: DLLs don't really have config files. At best, any purported config file is an indication of config you might want to apply to the consuming application's app/web config.

Comment: The plugipackager made my config file as dll.config. 
Are you saying this config is just a snap shot (read only) of my app.config and can’t be updated ?